# Loop unique values in nested data tree in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a data files with different items. Each item have nested tasks. I am trying to loop the nested tasks and present each task by the task type.

**YML DATA**

```
- name: Outside
  description: Description
  tasks:
  - type: Food
    name: Eat it outside
    status: working
  - type: Drinks
    name: Drink it outside
    status: working
- name: Inside
  description: Description
  tasks:
  - type: Food
    name: Eat it inside
    status: pending
  - type: Drinks
    name: Drink it inside
    status: working
```

**Liquid**

```
{% for item in site.data.info %}
    {% assign grouped-tasks-by-type = item.tasks | group_by: "type" %}
    {% for task in grouped-tasks-by-type %}
    <h2 class="task-type">{{ task.type }}</h2>
        <ul>
        {% for task in item.tasks %}
            {% if task.status == 'working' %}
                <li>{{ item.name }}: {{ task.name }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Expected result (HTML)**

```
<h2 class="task-type">Food</h2>
    <ul>
            <li>Outside: Eat it outside<li>
    </ul>
<h2 class="task-type">Drinks</h2>
    <ul>
            <li>Outside: Drink it outside<li>
            <li>Inside: Drink it inside<li>
    </ul>
```

However, I am getting a full blank result. Is this possible to do with `group_by`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope my algorithm below serves you well.  I was able to achieve your expect end result with the algorithm.  I was unable to utilize the `group_by` in my solution.  The sample code contains Liquid comment blocks to explain my thought process.

## Testing

I used the [minima git repo](https://github.com/jekyll/minima), with command `jekyll s`.  I placed your YML data in a file with path `_data/info.yml` in my locally cloned minima git repo.  I used `post.html` as the code sandbox.

You can print out the Liquid variables to the DOM by doing `{{ all_food_types | json }}` in the code.

## Solution

```
{%- comment -%} 
  End Goal: Find all the food types for <h2>.

  1.  Use map: "tasks" to gather all the tasks into a single array.
      This will cause the loss of Outside/Inside information for each task

  2.  Use map: "type" to create a list of food types ("Food", "Drinks")
  3.  Use uniq to remove duplicate food types from the array
{%- endcomment -%}

{% assign all_food_types = site.data.info | map: "tasks" | map: "type" | uniq %}

{%- comment -%}
  End Goal: Loop through all the data looking 
            for a specific food type (Food, Drinks) 
            and group them together
{%- endcomment -%}

{% for food_type in all_food_types %}
<h2 class="task-type">{{ food_type }}</h2>
    <ul>
      {% for item in site.data.info %}
        {% for task in item.tasks %}
            {% if task.status == 'working' and task.type == food_type %}
                <li>{{ item.name }}: {{ task.name }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

*An aside, for whatever reason, my liquid ends up using a lot of arrays and for-loops.*

Comment: I ran a test on my Jekyll project and it works perfectly. Great!